# Multiplying integers by booleans and understanding numpy array comparison

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a program in which there is a numpy array `a` whose elements can take three possible values: -1, 0 or 1. I am trying to multiply some of its elements by a number `c`. The idea is to obtain this behaviour:

```
for i,el in enumerate(a):
    if el == b:
        a[i] *= c
```

I came up with a solution that does not require any loops and works a couple of orders of magnitude faster than the previous one, this is the code I used to test them:

```
# Long array with random integers between -1 and 1

a = np.random.choice(3,1000000) - 1
a1 = a.copy()
a2 = a.copy()

# Reference values for b and c

b = 1
c = 10

# Solution with loop

t0 = time.time()

for i,el in enumerate(a1):
    if el == b:
        a1[i] *= c

t1 = time.time()

# Solution without loop

a2 = a2*((a2 == b)*c + (a2 != b))

t2 = time.time()

print("No loop: %f s"%(t1 - t0))
print("Loop: %f s"%(t2 - t1))
```

Although it seems to be working fine I'm not really happy with multiplying integers by booleans, but I don't know if I should, so I would appreciate if anyone could tell me a bit more about what is Numpy doing and/or if there is a better way to do this that I am not considering.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this multiplication, the boolean is treated as a 0/1 integer array.

Comment: I know, but it looks similar to what happens when you multiply an integer by a float ( 2*3.5), right?. I know that python treats that integer as a float when multiplying but I've being told that writing ( 2. * 3.5 ) helps to save time when there are a lot of repetitions @hpaulj

Comment: You can also avoid all these by just multiplying those values that equal b by c, for example `a[a==b] = a[a==b]*c`

Comment: I've being checking that out and it also works. It is faster than the loop but slower than `a2 = a2*((a2 == b)*c + (a2 != b))`. Thanks anyway. @StupidWolf

Comment: Or just `a[a == b] *= c`, or since `b` is just scalar 1, `a[a == b] = c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy will *cast* the bool type to the integer type, with `False` and `True` converted to 0 and 1 respectively.  This casting is safe, so don't worry, be happy.

```
In [8]: np.can_cast(np.bool8, np.intc)
Out[8]: True
```

If you prefer to be explicit, you could do that casting yourself by replacing `(a2 == b)` with `(a2 == b).astype(int)`, but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some comparative timings:

```
In [66]: %%timeit a2=a.copy()
    ...: a2*((a2==b)*10 + (a2!=b))
14.4 ms ± 36.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [67]: %%timeit a2=a.copy()
    ...: a2[a2==b] *= 10 
1.96 ms ± 75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [68]: %%timeit a2=a.copy()
    ...: a2[a2==b] = a2[a2==b]*10 
3.28 ms ± 5.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [69]: %%timeit a2=a.copy()
    ...: np.multiply(a2, 10, where=a2==b, out=a2)
1.63 ms ± 3.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The fastest ones only do one `a2==b` test.  The `multiply` with `where` parameter is fastest, but also bit harder to understand.

And to verify that the fastest produces the same thing:

```
In [73]: a2=a.copy();a2=a2*((a2==b)*10 + (a2!=b))
In [74]: a3=a.copy();np.multiply(a3, 10, where=a3==b, out=a3);
In [75]: np.allclose(a2,a3)
Out[75]: True
```